# Is it possible to avoid changing remote_url with ansible git module?

Tags: git, ansible

Is it possible to avoid changing `remote_url` with ansible `git` module?

When using git module with private-token after updating local repository, which I am using as a normal repo with other colleagues, I need to change remote by `git remote` command, because after running playbook, the git module changes remote to the one with private-token in url in it so after `git remote -v` it look like this:
`http://gitlab-ci-token:<private-token>@gitexample.com/path/to/repo`,
when it should look like this: `http://gitexample.com/path/to/repo`

Can I avoid such situation somehow?

Comment: Since the module does not accept login/password other than in the uri for http(s) repo addresses, I don't think it is possible. Would you be able to clone through ssh ? That would solve the issue and there are options to manage the key you use in the module.